# Unions of intervals are maximum

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

How we can prove that if $C_n$ is the class containing all the unions of at most $n$ positive intervals on the line. Then $C_n$ is $2n$ maximum.

Is it also true when we consider all the unions of exactly n intervals on the line?

Say that $\mathcal{C} \subseteq 2^X$ is $d$-maximum for $d \in \omega$ if for any ﬁnite $A \subseteq X$, $|\mathcal{C}|^A| := |\big\{C \cap A : C \in \mathcal{C}\big\}| = \sum_{i=0}^d {|A|\choose{i}}$ if $d < |A|$ and $2^{|A|}$ otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, but this is rather unclear. What do you mean by "$2n$ maximum"? Cardinality obviously can't be right, neither measure.

Comment: By positive interval do you mean an interval of non-zero length? And do you consider a half-line an interval or not? And what does 2n maximum mean?

Comment: I added the required definitions. Also we don't consider half lines as a positive interval; just $(a,b)$s such that $a<b$.